# Angular route's async resolver is still Observable

Tags: angular

I noticed that when you use an async route resolver in angular the value remains an Observable. For example, if you have a route like this

```
{
    path: '',
    component: FooComponent,
    resolve: { bar: barResolver },
},
```

And `barResolver` as follows

```
const barResolver: ResolveFn<string[]> = (): Observable<string[]> => {
    return of(['f', 'o', 'o']);
};
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-axrkxs?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Ffoo%2Fbar.resolver.ts,src%2Ffoo%2Ffoo.component.ts,src%2Ffoo%2Ffoo.component.html&title=Angular%20Starter)

You cannot directly access this data via `activatedRoute.data` as it is still an Observable, so you have to do something like

```
{{activatedRoute.data | async | json}}
```

Ideally I would like to do

```
{{activatedRoute.data | json}}
```

Is there a way to have the data available in `activatedRoute.data` and not the observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the [`snapshot`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot) of the [`activatedRoute`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) to directly access the property like so!

```
{{(activatedRoute && activatedRoute.snapshot && activatedRoute.snapshot.data) | json}}
```

> Note: Since the example stackblitz you provided does not render inside a `router-outlet` the data is empty!